# why am i getting role claims sometimes namespaced and sometimes without namespace

Tags: jwt, access-token, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 for authentication. Some clients use reference tokens, some clients use selfcontaining tokens.

- For reference tokens I use the IntrospectionClient to exchange the
  accesstokens for claims.
- For Selfcontaining tokens I use the "JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken" to exchange the accesstoken for claims.

For the first I get the role claims with key "role", for the second I get the role claims with key "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"

Any idea how to line this up to one key for both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying what technology are your "Selfcontaining" clients using, but I'm assuming it is some .NET.

Here are the solutions for:

**.NET Core:**

In your `Startup.cs` (of the client project) add this line:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

[Documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html#creating-an-mvc-client) for .NET Core.

**.NET Framework:**

Again in the `Startup.cs` add the following:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

[Documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html#claims-transformation) for .NET Framework.

This should fix your problem, and all of your claims will come with the short names.